# Gain back edit permissions as admin - MS Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharepoint-admin-center

I have been granted admin rights to a sharepoint folder, so I can edit the permissions to read only. Now I set the permissions for every group for this file as read only, including myself apparently, and I cannot remove my own restrictions. I need to overwrite the file at some point, which I cannot do right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the site admin for help.

For this situation(everyone only have read permission to this folder), only site admin can re-grant you admin rights to this folder.

No matter how you change the permission of the folder, the site admin would have full control to this folder(also for the site).